# Removing First 2 years Real Time Software Testing Experience

Tags: work-experience

I finished my education in May 2007 and below is my Software Tester job (real time) experience.

> **Company A** - March - 2008 to Feb 2010 ( 2 years)
>   **Company B** - March - 2010 to Nov 2011 ( 1 year 6 months)
>   **Company C** - Nov   - 2011 to till date( 5 years )

Right now, I do not have any Automation experience and I have done a course on Selenium WebDriver to get a job. I thought of removing the first 2 years of experience in company A.

Can someone suggest if it is better to do that? If I am trying to apply to Company D, HR from Company D can call my previous companies and know my details.

Note : I am not worried about my salary.

Comment: This post is hard to read for the general Workplace.SE reader. Could you rewrite it without all the technical jargon?

Comment: Why do you think not listing your experience at company A will help you?

Comment: If company a was over ten years ago and you needed the space on the resume for more current jobs, that;s ok, but there seems to be no reason at all to remove it right now.

Answer (score 12):

Are you proposing simply leaving a two year gap on your resume? Future employers will assume one of the following:

- you did nothing worthwhile in that time
- you have something to hide about what you did in that time

Both of these are far worse than the simple fact that you did a job that isn't particularly relevant to the one you hope to have. Don't do it.

Comment: +1 Looking at it the other way round, continuous job-holding for several years is a strong positive for any job.

Answer (score 3):

So you had a job as a software tester at Company A, B, and C, but you want to remove Company A from your CV?

It seems an odd proposition, the more experience you have on the CV, the better it would be for you. Does it cause some concern if the HR company did contact company A?

Unless you have something to hide from working at Company A, I would leave it on. Even if you did have something to hide, they will ask about gaps in your CV and you should answer honestly, so they will most likely discover that you did work for Company A.

In the end, removing it from your CV is doing you more harm than good and should be left on.

> Can some one suggest me, how far it is good, If I am trying in Company D, HR from Company D can call to my previous companies and know my details.

It's always better to have experience on a CV than to remove it. Companies don't always follow up with previous employers, however it shows you've held a job for a while and gives you a nice talking point during an interview.

Comment: Right now I am working as Manual Tester , Just started learning Selenium and now If I would want to shift to other company with 8 + experience as Individual Contributor , that is not possible and hence thought of removing the 2 years experience .Please suggest

Comment: Why is it not possible? There is something we're not seeing here and we need you to paint a bigger picture. Could you please explain what the issue is?

Comment: Can you give suggest future career path after 8+ experience in testing

Comment: The world is your oyster, you can move into a lot of things from testing, however what you asking is out of scope for this site. Again, I'm not seeing why you need to remove this experience from your CV